# Пройтись циклом в теле шаблонной строки

Tags: javascript

Привет. Можно ли пройтись циклом по массиву внутри шаблонной строки? Например, есть массив:

```
"carriers": [
  0: "S7",
  1: "SU"
]
```

Который я хочу вывести, например, в строку:

```
element.append(`
    <h2>Carriers:</h2>
    <div class="carriers">
        <img src="/img/carriers/S7.png" />
        <img src="/img/carriers/SU.png" />
    </div>
`);
```

И, да, меня интересует решение конкретно в теле `append()`(специфика задачи).

Answer (score 1):

Если очень хочется, то можно вот так:

```
const carriers = ["S7", "SU"];

element.append(`
    <div class="carriers">
        ${carriers.map(name => '<img src="/img/carriers/' + name + '.png" />').join('')}
    </div>
`);
```

Но лучше так никогда-никогда не делать. Вместо этого возьмите любой JS шаблонизатор и используйте его.

Comment: _"Но лучше так никогда-никогда не делать."_ - jsx настороженно наблюдает за тобой)

Comment: JS-шаблонизатор?

Comment: Если вопрос мне, то скорее нет, чем да.

Comment: @Qwertiy, речь не о JSX. Но даже там, сложные конструкции правильнее выносить из `map`/`reduce` функций. Хотя, как всегда, могут быть варианты.

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin тысячи их. Например, [Handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev а какой из них по вашей версии самый производительный и удобный, etc?

Comment: Производительность нужно мерить. А по удобству - мне нравится уже упомянутый выше Handlebars.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev мне важно, чтобы Babel его не пожевал.